# extract video id from youtube urls in content

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a lot of youtube urls in a string.
those youtube urls were suppose to be video ids only but due to an error I have urls and need to be able to remove the garbage and keep the ids only without touching any other of the content.
and I need to do this in JavaScript.

this is an example of the content:

```
"pre text videoid=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CF1zRWVdDnA videoid=https://www.youtube.com/embed/u4x9YyRnFDE?start=54 videoid=https://youtu.be/loyfGyvpv1o, post text"
```

this is what I'm trying to achieve as a result:

```
"pre text videoid=CF1zRWVdDnA videoid=u4x9YyRnFDE videoid=loyfGyvpv1o, post text"
```

this is the code I've tried that almost accomplishes it:

```js
var content = "pre text videoid=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CF1zRWVdDnA videoid=https://www.youtube.com/embed/u4x9YyRnFDE?start=54 videoid=https://youtu.be/loyfGyvpv1o, post text";

result = content.replace(/ [^\}\"\']*?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:embed\/|watch\?v\=)?/gi, 'videoid=1');
```

the regex fails to get this one:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/u4x9YyRnFDE?start=54
```

so I guess it's a regex problem, not a javascript one.
but I need to be able to get the id from ones with that pattern too.

here is the jsFiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/a8g8a9mp/10/

help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regexp, it is a more or less primitive list of strings to cut out

```js
var content = "pre text videoid=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CF1zRWVdDnA videoid=https://www.youtube.com/embed/u4x9YyRnFDE?start=54 videoid=https://youtu.be/loyfGyvpv1o, post text";

result = content.replace(/https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com|https:\/\/youtu\.be\/|\/watch\?v\=|\/embed\/|\?start=[0-9]+/gi, '');

console.info(result)
```

Comment: thanks but i need something that will work with any additional parameter to the video id.
there is also "rel=0" for example and youtube adds ones every now and than